# Implicit styles binding content to a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to learn a WPF/xaml by recreating metro style window and controls myselft without external library.

What I'M strugling is binding a content(text) into a textblock inside an implicit style. What i want is several textblocks on my form header, telling me where in the app I am - and this has to be shared among all other forms.

So title of the form was easy, just using template binding. 
But how du you achievie the same result with other values that are not properties of the base class (window).

[image]

What I want is to set PAGE | SUBPAGE set dynamicly on each form, but the style is implicit inside a .xaml file and ResourceDictionary.

SOmething like setting a title?:

```
     <TextBlock x:Name="WindowTitleTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="8 -1 0 0"  FontSize="16"  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
```

Comment: More texts means you need more `TextBlock`s. Not sure where your current `TextBlock` is located. Is it inside window template? Standard window? Have you thought to make a *custom window* with more dependency properties, which you then access with `TemplateBinding`s?

Comment: My new TextBlock is inside an Implicit style with the textblock i showed. A normal window is then using this style.

Comment: How are you supposed to set "PAGE" and "SUBPAGE" if there are no such properties...?